# Why does "typeof" not need parentheses?

Tags: javascript, typeof

Is there any difference between `typeof (myVariable)` compared to `typeof myVariable`?

Both work, but coming from PHP, I don't understand why this function can use parenthesis or not.

Comment: To add, it is an operator similar to `+` or `-` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Because `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: this is a real question, not a not real question.

Comment: Why closed? Question is extremely important... which one is correct? Is one deprecated or can be used to cover more browsers backwards compatible?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `typeof` keyword represents an *operator* in `Javascript` programming.

The correct definition for `typeof` operator in the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator) is :

```
typeof[(]expression[)] ;
```

This is the reason behind the use of `typeof` as `typeof(expression)` or `typeof expression`.

Coming to *why* it has been implemented as such is probably to let the developer handle the level of visibility in his code. As such, it is possible to use a clean conditional statement using typeof :

```
if ( typeof myVar === 'undefined' )
  // ...
;
```

Or defining a more complex expression using the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) :

```
const isTrue = (typeof (myVar = anotherVar) !== 'undefined') && (myVar === true);
```

**EDIT :**

In some cases, using parentheses with the `typeof` operator makes the code written less prone to ambiguity.

Take for instance the following expression where the `typeof` operator is used without parentheses. Would `typeof` return the type of the result of the concatenation between an empty string literal and a number, or the type of the string literal ?

```
typeof "" + 42
```

Looking at the definition of the operator stated above and the [precedence of the operators `typeof` and `+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3ks45k7(v=vs.94).aspx), it appears that the previous expression is equivalent to :

```
typeof("") + 42 // Returns the string `string42`
```

In this case, using parentheses with `typeof` would bring more clarity to what you are trying to express :

```
typeof("" + 42) // Returns the string `string`
```

Comment: Just to nitpick on an almost 6 years old answer: I think `var isTrue` is missing a parentheses. You have three opening parentheses and four closing. Which brings me to a point to be made - having parentheses does not readable code make. In some cases, the redundant parentheses just makes things harder to decipher,

Comment: Thanks @JerriKangasniemi for pointing out the typo. And yes, I do agree with your statement on readability, I just made an edit. In fact, the true reason behind this implementation is to allow complex expressions within the scope of the `typeof` operator (e.g assignments or use of ternary operators) which indeed generally makes code  awful to read by humans.

Comment: Maybe `(typeof "") + 42 // Returns the string 'string42'` should be added? Just as unambiguous without the added confusion.

Comment: `typeof` is specified as [“`typeof` _UnaryExpression_”](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator). The MSDN link is obsolete; this isn’t the “correct” specification.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Updated the link, thanks!

Comment: @HalimQarroum I also meant the syntax `typeof[(]expression[)] ;`. The parentheses are not part of the `typeof` definition.

Comment: @HalimQarroum The updated link does not support the claim in your answer