# Why is "typeof" the same as "typeof()"?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript, and i saw in the code that is the same to use `typeof` and `typeof()`, for example:

The result is number in both cases:

```
console.log(typeof 1); 
console.log(typeof(1));
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843805/why-does-typeof-not-need-parentheses?rq=1

Comment: Same reason that `1+2` is the same as `(1)+(2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typeof` is, according to [ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), an unary operator - the same as `void` and `delete`, for example. Wrapping its expression with grouping `()` is only done for convenience (and - in theory - to override the default precedence), but never it's treated as a function call.

Comment: Thank you, thus typeof is an unary operator.

Comment: For example the unary operator sizeof in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Because "typeof" is an operator (not a function, not an object), and an operator can be used in an expression with parenthesis:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Answer (score 1):

typeof is an operator, just like +, -, %, && etc. It is not a method and "1" is not a parameter being passed, brackets are not required. However it will accept brackets as they just specify the order of operation, just like (1) + (2) is acceptable even though the brackets are not necessary. So the example you gave is acceptable in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The typeof operator is not a function. You can surround the operand with parentheses so that the expression looks like a function call, but the parentheses will simply act as a grouping operator (second only to the comma operator in the obscurity pecking order!). In fact you can decorate the operand with all manner of punctuation without derailing the operator.

```
typeof (2) //"number"
typeof(2) //"number"
typeof ("a", 3) //"number"
typeof (1 + 1) //"number"
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you wanted to show with your third example. With `typeof ("a', 3)`, one gets the description of type of result of `"a", 3` expression - and that's `3`, because that's how comma operator works. )