# What's the meaning of UnaryExpression of ES6 Spec documentation?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I'm curious about the meaning of UnaryExpression of ES6 Spec documentation.
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator

Actually I was wonder about why typeof operator could accept both operand without parenthesis, also operand with parenthesis.
ex) typeof a / typeof (a)

So I searched on the internet and found ES6 Spec documentation guide me that typeof operator could accept UnaryExpression.

> UnaryExpression : typeof UnaryExpression

and also found out this SO answer.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843896/911528

In this article, user Halim Qarroum answered,

> The correct definition for typeof operator in the specification is : typeof[(]expression[)]

I don't know the exact meaning of UnaryExpression.
(I couldn't find out. Yes the definition is there but they are so abstract.)

And I'm curious how Halim Qarroum could infer that answer through only see the spec documentation.

Does [(]expression[)] is equals to UnaryExpression?
Does [] means omit-able?

Comment: That answer is outdated. The source link points to MSDN which in turn points to MDN which say the syntax is `typeof operand`. No parens. One could add parens to improve readability or enforce precedence.

Comment: @SalmanA Even if the SO's link I quoted here is outdated but I think my question is not outdated. I'm asking about the UnaryExpression on the ES6 Spec documentation. Leroy Stav answered me perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unary expression is an expression with only one token.
Unary Operators (such as `typeof` or `++`) take as an operand a unary expression.

Parenthesis, when wrapping a unary expression, are ignored by the parser.  Hence, `typeof(i)` and `(i)++` are equivalent to `typeof i` and `i++`, respectively.

Yes, in developer documentation square brackets denote optional things.  usually used for optional function arguments, but understandable in the answer you quoted.

Comment: You told me all about what I want to know. Thank you veryvery much!

Comment: Could you tell me more about the token? "A unary expression is an expression with only one token" in this paragraph, I'm qurious about what meaning of 'token' exactly.

Comment: A "token" is developer-speak for "part of a string".  For example, if you (in javascript) execute `someString.split(' ')`, you are splitting `someString` into tokens, delimited by a space.   In terms of language compilation, when describing things like "expressions" and "statements" etc etc, one things of them in terms of "which tokens in the source code are relevant to what underlying mechanism?"  So "expression with only one token" would be "when the part of the code that we are looking at is expected to be an expression and that expression will end up to be a single reference"

Comment: so specifically, the ES6 doc you copied over, `UnaryExpression : typeof UnaryExpression` basically translates to the following:  "Any instance of `typeof UnaryExpression` in the code is also considered to be a UnaryExpression.  Also, the only acceptable way to call `typeof` is when the operand is a UnaryExpression."  Further, as described in https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression, any expression can be wrapped in parenthesis and yield itself.  Therefore, `typeof i` and typeof (i)` are functionally equivalent (and in fact yield *identical* abstract syntax trees)

Comment: It much more clear. So now I can understand why "typeof (i)" and "typeof i" is same. And also, I can figure out why "typeof typeof i" also working. Thank you again. You are really good at getting my point.