# What is the type of typeof in JS

Tags: javascript, types

In my console's browser, when I do :

```
console.log(typeof(typeof))
```

it returns an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`

Why is that? Why can't I get typeof's type ?

Comment: Because it's a keyword. Like `return` and `if` and `function` among others. It's only valid as part of an expression, it's not an expression by itself.

Comment: Also typeof is not a function - it should be `typeof typeof` if it had worked

Comment: @mplungjan related [Why does “typeof” not need parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843805/why-does-typeof-not-need-parentheses) - it also includes a definition of exactly what `typeof` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`typeof` is an **operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) like `&&`, `=`, `==`, or `!`.

It isn't a value, variable or identifier.

---

As with any operator, when you apply it you get a value, and `typeof something` will give you a string. (Just as `something == somethingelse` will give you a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

First line on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) says

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
> unevaluated operand.

So clearly, since it is a operator you can not use it this way.

What could makes sense is

```js
console.log(typeof typeof 2)
```

this always outputs `string`.

Comment: `typeof typeof x` will *always* return `"string"` for any value of `x`, even if it's undeclared. With the sole exception of a temporal deadzone `console.log(typeof typeof x); let x = 42` in that case you'd get an error.

Answer (score 0):

**Typeof** is a an **operator** and also a **keyword** not a **data struture** like **Array, Number** and so on.

It is like you try to find the type of `var` or `let`